# stop flickable item from exceeding boundaries in qml

Tags: qt, qml, scrollbar, flickable

This question is regarding QtQuick 1.1, QML, Qt 4.5

I am making a windows style scroll bar for showing text area.

Using `Flickable` with `TextEdit` inside, and simple rectangle parts for scrollbar.

Problem is **When I flick the text, it shows contents outside the text also**

For example see the scrollbar example and picture attached below.

I don't want to show the area outside that image. Stop if reach the border.

Also is there any in-built scrollbar module in QtQuick 1.1

Thanks!!

[image: outside of image boundary is shown]

Comment: Tried to clip it? clip: true. I don't have Qt 4.5, so I can't test it with that version, but QtQuick 1.1 Flickable seems to have the property clip.

Comment: If the list is long, but parent is small we `clip` the content. Can u imagine in smartphone we swipe the list of items down, even though we reach the top item, it still shows empty space top of the first item and then slowly moves up.

Comment: The Flickable's behavior at boundaries is usually controlled via the boundsBehavior property: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qml-flickable.html#boundsBehavior-prop
Have you tried setting that to `Flickable.StopAtBounds`?

Comment: @KevinKrammer  That Worked Perfect. I used as `boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds`. Just one more. Do you know any method for scrolling the text down one line at a time if a button i cliked?

Comment: Hmm, nothing concrete, but maybe try to get the delta height from `font.pixelSize` and then adding that to the flickable's `contentY`?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to disable flicking in horizontal direction using

**flickableItem.flickableDirection: Flickable.VerticalFlick**

inside ScrollView block